# Installing R packages in macOS Mojave: Error in if (nzchar(SHLIB_LIBADD))

Tags: r, macos, installation, dependencies

I have been trying to install R packages directly from the terminal but I am struggling much more than setting up the libraries I want in Windows. Sometimes it works if I install every single dependency for more complex packages by downloading them from CRAN and placing them in the R folder.
I appreciate this is not efficient but the recurrent error if I run R within the terminal while installing some of the packages is the following:

```
** libs
Error in if (nzchar(SHLIB_LIBADD)) SHLIB_LIBADD else character() : 
argument is of length zero
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/<package name>’
```

[...]

```
In install.packages("<package name>") :
installation of package ‘fpc’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have been looking across many forums but the only solution I found so far is to install single dependencies manually by downloading them and dropping them in the master R folder. It is taking way longer than expected.
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should use R-proper vs the anaconda version of it or at least try that since it's likely the issue (I've been on Mojave since WWDC and have had no issues but I use a proper R vs anaconda crippled R)

Comment: Yes, my final objective is to show all the outputs of my R code in a Jupyter notebook since it is an html format that can be shared more easily. Yet, I am unable to understand what the error actually means and how to fix it

Comment: In a nutshell, only by installing packages via conda I managed to get them installed, not from within R. Also various dependencies have to be updated so the whole library compilation is a much more time consuming process and a lot of work needs to go in C++ compilation alongside updating dependencies that are not R-specific. I still wonder what the error means though...

Answer (score 19):

in my case (centos 7):
`/home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf` is a empty file!

```
find ~ -name Makeconf
/home/xilab/miniconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.6.1-hce969dd_0/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
/home/xilab/miniconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.6.1-h8900bf8_2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
/home/xilab/miniconda3/envs/python2.7/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
/home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
```

`/home/xilab/miniconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.6.1-hce969dd_0/lib/R/etc/Makeconf` is not empty,so:

```
 mv /home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf /home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.backup
 cp /home/xilab/miniconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.6.1-hce969dd_0/lib/R/etc/Makeconf /home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf
```

problem solved!

Comment: recently I encountered another problem(``zlib.h: No such file or directory``), and I checked the ``Makeconf`` file again, I found out that I need to change the ``-I`` path.

Comment: ```vi /home/xilab/miniconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf

# replace /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3 with /home/xilab/miniconda3
:%s/\/opt\/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/\/home\/xilab\/miniconda3/g```

Answer (score 10):

I have seen this problem in conda version of R where /yours/anaconda/environment/lib/R/etc/ has a file Makeconf.mro.original together with an empty Makeconf file. This should not be intended.

During installation of some packages R checks what is within this Makeconf file, one such check is for SHLIB_LIBADD.
I just backed up the empty (or whatever) Makeconf file. Then copied Makeconf.mro.original to Makeconf.

This solved my case.

EDIT:

Recently I saw in centos-machine that Makeconf.mro.original file is not made after install.packages("name of library") failed. There is no easy solution for this.

In my case R installation was inside a conda environment. So, I created a new conda environment with R installation. The fresh installation has a Makeconf file in etc directory. So, I copied the Makeconf file from fresh R to my previously working R's etc directory.

It may be better to keep a backup copy of Makeconf from etc to a Makeconf.bak for future problems, in your working R etc directory.

I hope this helps for some cases.

Comment: Thank you! Your workaround also worked on a Linux system where I was having the exact same problem.

Comment: Great find!  This solved a problem with `Rcpp` not working for me

Comment: Can you help me locate Makeconf.mro.original file. I can't see in in anaconda/environment/lib/R/etc/

Comment: @Samir. It may happen that while installing compilation failed in a different step and Makeconf.pro.original not created. Anyway, you should look at anaconda/envs/NameOfYourEnviroment/lib/R/etc or depending on how R is installed may be look in anaconda/lib/R/etc

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to run `install.packages("RPostgres")` in a conda-installed version of R . The solution was to use `conda` as the package manager instead of R's `install.packages` function. That meant running these commands at a normal system command prompt (not in R):

```
conda search -c conda-forge RPostgres
# shows various versions of r-rpostgres
conda install -c conda-forge r-rpostgres
```